# Python Qt 4 not initializing window

Tags: python, qt, qt4

I am just learning PyQt4. I am running Linux Mint (Ubuntu 14.04 based), with the package `python-qt4` installed. I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
```

I am using both PyDev, and my terminal to run the application yet the program terminates within 1 second, without showing any window.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to start the main eventloop - typically this is done by adding

`app.exec_()`

as last line to your code.

You should probably check out some examples, e.g. on the web: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/.

Comment: Thank so much! The youtube video I was watching didn't have that line of code, but adding `app.exec_()` works! =)